# Why does my cat meow when she stands on the railing?

Tags: cats, behavior

This happens at least once daily, and it started around two or three weeks ago. One of our two cats from the same litter (she is smaller, much more shy) began jumping right onto the stairs railing and then she would meow continuously until I come out of my room. I noticed that it only happens when she knows there is someone upstairs, and that she will stop meowing once she sees me and will come towards me for petting (while still on the railing).

I'm not so concerned about her falling off the railing as this never happened before - both of our cats take extra care in walking on the railing. However, I am interested in finding out what my cat wants from doing this. Is this perhaps related to cats bringing dead prey to their owners, as they may expect to get praised for doing so?

Comment: "Hey, look!" Gets your attention, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cats are smart enough to repeat behavior that results in some desired response from you. If your cat's behavior results in the attention she wants, she will learn to repeat that behavior.

Cats like to be in higher places; it allows them to see things better and is a better defensive position if they are threatened.

When you combine both cat traits above, you have a reasonable explanation for your cat's behavior.